# Wordpress Woocommerce Subscription

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, bundles

Здравствуйте. Имеется wordpress с плагином woocommerce. У меня есть два вариативных товара, которые находятся в bundle. Есть плагин subscription (от woocommerce) который разрешает подписываться на товары. Так вот, проблема в том, что я не могу сделать bundle с продуктами подпиской. Если у кого была такая проблема, прошу отозваться. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я использовал: WooCommerce – Subscribe All the Things

[Ссылка на гит](https://github.com/Prospress/woocommerce-subscribe-all-the-things/releases)
Устанавливать как обычный плагин.
Главное, чтобы variable продукты не были типа Variable Subscription, а были просто Variable Product.

Настраивать подписку надо в самом Bundle.